# Ubuntu Installation Not Working in Battery Mode

Tags: 18.04, crash

I have a few serious issues with my Ubuntu installation, all of them only when working with the battery.
I have dual boot between W10 and Ubuntu 18.04 lts, and both of them work perfectly when charging, but once using battery only UBUNTU is the only one who doesn't work!
The problems:

1) Random Blinking;
2) Crashes/Frozen WHITE screen after unlocking my session or recovering from suspension mode;
3) The scariest one: Random sounds of electrical shocks, equal to the sound of a hard reset shutdown!
4) More recently whenever I tried to reboot my PC it asks my password and it unlocks to the desktop but just for a few seconds before freezing!

To prove my idea I tried to reboot my PC and each time after my password Desktop ends up freezing. To restart I use de alt+sysqr+ reisub shortcut but I end up freezing again. BUT at the moment that I turn the power adapter on it goes smooth!
In some crash/freezing situation, my PC goes to a command screen (picture below) before going to the password unlock screen again and crashing definitely.

[image: IMG]

I really don't want to re install UBUNTU before exploring all sugestions.
I already tried with a live Cd I ran the try Ubuntu, and I was able to initiate and work (both battery mode and plug in), the problem was that every time that I tried to reboot, log out or shut down all my attempts resulted in a crash/freeze.
I ran Gparted to check for partition problems and nothing was found.

I would appreciate more suggestions.

Hint:
A few days ago I installed preload, tlp and cpufreq. But I had everything associated with them removed(I think)

Specs:
SO:
Ubuntu 18.04 lts

PC:
MSI GE62 Apache Pro
IntelCore I7
NVidea GTX960m

[update]
After another try, it crashed and started to show pci troubleshooting:
[https://imgur.com/PgOqcDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdP8g.jpg)

---

well I did a clean install of my dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, and I did just install the basic, and once again itś working smoothly, but the problem appears when I disconnect my charger from my computer:
i) If I'm working in Ubuntu, and I disconnect my charger it eventually crashes after a few seconds maybe a minute.
ii) If I try to turn on my computer without my power adapter, it gets stuck in a loop in the user authentication page, or it simply crashes.

I don't have this problem with the windows installation neither have this problem with live cd Ubuntu.

Please, can someone give me a hint.
I tried already to disable all power savings options, suspension options,I used grub parameter pci=nomsi and pci=noaer,Tlt,...

After one of the many crashes I had this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rbRA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Dell G7. With much less side effects, but still. After a very painful troubleshooting, I found out hidden inside the BIOS, some setting corresponding to the power management. It turned out that every time I was on plain battery mode, the BIOS was set up to go into a "best battery life" state. Those setting were opposing to those Ubuntu uses, so that was why I had the issues. Everything was corrected by altering the Grub loader, and adding some parameters for the pci manipulation. So maybe you can work towards that road now.

Comment: Hello I think the answer is in pci problems, can you tell more details about the solution you implemented.